# How to Display Modified Time and Modified By Fields Correctly with Powershell

Tags: powershell, date-time, modified

I have a script that outputs to CSV all items/files from all Lists and Libraries. In addition, it displays the current and previous versions of an item/file. This also displays which user modified the file for each version and also displays the date/time the file was modified for every version:

```
function Get-DocInventory([string]$siteUrl) {
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://contoso.com/sites/Depts3/HBG"
foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {


foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
foreach($version in $item.Versions){
$data = @{
"Version" = $version.VersionLabel
"List Name" = $list.Title
"Created By" = $item["Author"]
"Created Date" = ($item["Created"] -as [datetime]).DateTime
"Modified By" = $version["Editor"]
"Modified Date" = ($version["Modified"] -as [datetime]).DateTime
"Item Name" = $item.Name

}
New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "List Name", "Item Name", "Version", "Created By", "Created Date", "Modified By", "Modified Date"
}
}
$web.Dispose();
}
}




Get-DocInventory  | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\GenerateReport.csv
```

Below is a sample of what the script outputs:

[image]

And below is an excel example of what I see when I go to the Version History of the Lions.pdf file:

[image]

I have 2 problems:

- The column Modified By is displaying email and domain username which is not required.
- My script displays the column Modified Date as 5 hours ahead. The script output for Version 1 of Lions.pdf displays time as 11:23 AM. But when I go to Version History of Lions.pdf it says that Version 1 was modified at 6:23 AM. The time discrepancy is the same across the board as 5 hours ahead which is incorrect.

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here. Can someone please assist in the issue I am having? My main concern is the time and I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: First I would check the timezone set of the machine where the script is running.